# python: read a folder with file name and file concept

Tags: python, xml, list, contain

I have a dataframe (below), for the column 'name',
I want to delete the (for example the first row)

```
'/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/'
```

and

```
'.txt'
```

just keep the word like (example of first row)

```
'Topic+Topic_of_Situation.shortageglut'
```

in each line

```
,n_1,n_2,name
0,water,shortage,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Situation.shortageglut.txt
1,supply,shortage,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Situation.shortageglut.txt
2,skill,shortage,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Situation.shortageglut.txt
214,income,policy,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Plan&Deal&Rules.rules.legal.txt
215,immigration,policy,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Plan&Deal&Rules.rules.legal.txt
216,health,policy,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Plan&Deal&Rules.rules.legal.txt
485,license,agreement,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Plan&Deal&Rules.deal.txt
486,lease,agreement,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Plan&Deal&Rules.deal.txt
487,immunity,agreement,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Plan&Deal&Rules.deal.txt
488,franchise,agreement,/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/Topic+Topic_of_Plan&Deal&Rules.deal.txt
```

Comment: Your example shows a CSV file, not a dataframe. Do you plan to use `pandas` or a CSV reader?

Comment: It's a data frame, I just print it to the csv for read. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.str.strip()` methods:

```
prefix = '/Users/xccxken/Desktop/NNRelease/paperVersion/'
suffix = '.txt'
df['name'] = df['name'].str.rstrip(suffix).str.lstrip(prefix)
```

Or regular expressions:

```
description = r'([^/]+)\.txt'
df['name'] = df['name'].str.extract(description)
```

Comment: thanks. can you tell me if i want to extract  'Topic+Topic_of_Situation.othersituation' to 'Topic+Topic_of_Situation',how to write this 'description2 ' .  'Topic+Topic_of_Situation' to 'Topic',how to write 'description3',thanks!

Comment: You have several different patterns in your frame. You may want to read more about Python regular expressions (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and play with them online to find the expression that works:  https://regex101.com/